# Javascript function not clicked whitin certain time

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, time, click

I need help (again). What I would like to have is a function which if there has not been clicked one time on a button in a certain time, a div will be showed. To be more clear, I'm looking for this kind of code:

```
    function MyFunction() {
if(not clicked one time in 8000 milliseconds)
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Does somebody knows how I should code this? Thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3c3vojho/ Something like this should be barely enough. Next time I would recommend you to put some more effort before posting, you could've come up with something more to be entirely honest.

Comment: @briosheje thank you for reaction, I will try your code. I'm new here and do not fully understand Stackoverflow yet. So I'm curious: why is it important to come with something more?

Comment: because the stackoverflow format is all about a specific problem to solve showing what you have attempted so far, having a piece of code that briefly gives an idea of what you need to accomplish may not be exactly considered in-topic here, despite as you can see someone usually gives a shot to any question. Also, for the next time, try to clarify the current input (the code you have attempted to write, regardless with or without errors in it) and the desired output :). In any case, either choose setTimeout or setInterval to accomplish such.

Comment: Also, here is a further explanation of the code I've posted above: https://jsfiddle.net/3c3vojho/1/

Comment: @briosheje I understand, thanks! Your code worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can "set a timer" to execute a function using `setTimeout`. This function returns an id that you can use to cancel the timer. Here's an example:

```js
var clickTimeout = null;

var cancel = function() {
  clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
};

var start = function() {
  cancel();
  document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "none";
  clickTimeout = setTimeout(onDone, 2000);
};


var onDone = function() {
  document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementById("cancel").addEventListener("click", cancel);
document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", start);

start();
```

```html
<button id="cancel">click me</button>
<button id="restart">restart</button>




<div id="showMe" style="display: none">Timed out</div>
```